# when I network.bind_host: localhost , it doesn't working

Tags: elasticsearch

I install elasticsearch in aws ubuntu 14.04

[install document](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-6-%E2%80%94-using-elasticsearch)

i change some settings in `elasticsearch.yml`

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
#network.bind_host: 192.168.0.1
```

to

```
network.bind_host: localhost
```

the document told me localhost is good at secure

when I start elasticsearch

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart

* Stopping Elasticsearch Server                                              [ OK ]
* Starting Elasticsearch Server
```

and when I send curl

```
sudo curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

so I change `network.bind_host`

```
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
```

and

```
sudo curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'

{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "****",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_***",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.2",
    "build_hash" : "e12r1r33r3fs593f7202acbd816e8ec",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-09-14T09:49:53Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

but I think `0.0.0.0` is so danger when i product my web site

please somebody help me?

Comment: Try `_local_` instead of `localhost` ([from here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/modules-network.html))

Comment: @Val i try using your advice, but doesn't working same error,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you should be having your `network.host` set to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` within your elasticsearch yml.

```
network.host: localhost <-- try 127.0.0.1 as well
```

Normally the `network.bind_host` binds to your `network.host` by default. You could have a look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#advanced-network-settings) maybe for more details.

And just in case, try adding the `http.port` as well, so that you could make sure that you could access the ES port, which could look something like this.

```
http.port: 9200
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @Darth_Vader `your my father` haha I solved my problem using your solution